# How to hide a progress bar in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

Guys I am working on a flight booking api integration project. Every thing is working fine when I click for search flights on button progress bar comes in a fine way.But Problem I am getting is that I am calling progress bar from javascript and when there are validation error on the page still progress bar shows up. So my question is how to hide progressbar when there are validation errors on page I am using asp.net server validations.

My javascript is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowProgress() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var modal = $('<div />');
                modal.addClass("modal");
                $('body').append(modal);
                var loading = $(".loading");
                loading.show();
                var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
                var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
                loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
            }, 200);
        }


         function changes() {

             ShowProgress();

         }
    </script>
```

I am calling it on button click like thsi:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" OnClientClick ="changes();"  runat="server" ValidationGroup ="r" Text="Search" Height="40px" 
                Width="134px" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
```

My progress bar div is like this:

```
<div class="loading" align="center">
        Loading. Please wait.<br />
        <img src="load.gif" style="height:50px; width :50px;" alt="" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Well, hiding the progress bar is easy. I think your real question is "How do I detect validation failure and take action"

Comment: yes @Basic but I also want to know better way of hiding it.

Comment: `$(".loading").remove();` will remove all divs with the class of `loading`. If you want to give it an id to be more specific, you can do `$("#someId").remove();`

Comment: @basic how to check for validation

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't used webforms in years. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really simple No need to hide progress bar. What I did I showed progress bar only if page has no validation error.For that I assigned validation group to each validation control and search button as "r" then check validation errors as :

```
function changes() {
            if (Page_ClientValidate("r"))
                ShowProgress();


        }
```

Modified changes() function.Thanks @Basic

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)